# any way to cross-connect questions?

Tags: feature-request

My feature request (idea), is simple, sometimes we get here at U&L questions that can get better answers at ServerFault (for example), they have a relation to here, since these questions have a touch with U&L, but the whole scope is ServerFault related.

My idea is to create the ability to put a link to this question at ServerFault, hence the question owner can get a better answer, and everybody would be happier.

Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27509/webgui-for-virtualization) question for example, it has a U&L touch but in ServerFault or WebApps, this guy can get a better answer.

Comment: This would probably be better on the main meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com) since it's not really specific to U&L. Please do search there, there have been a lot of discussions about similar ideas (there's even a cross-posting tag). Eg: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11600/allow-cross-posting-between-serverfault-com-and-superuser-com, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64995/please-provide-the-ability-to-cross-post-questions-to-multiple-stack-exchange-co, and others. (Caution: meta.SO is fun, but... different.)

Comment: @Mat It's fine to post generic stuff on our meta instead of meta.SO, but I do think this was already brought up there

Comment: Flag them for migration.

Answer (score 1):

What many people do is comment on the post with a link to the related question from the foreign site. It's all the better if such commentary is done on both posts.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not what migration does?

The question will still be visible on the original site...